# Unable to solve this Express.js/ JavaScript programming issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

```
try {
console.log('11111')
const {
  data: { tasks },
} = await axios.get('/api/v1/tasks')
console.log('22222 ' + await axios.get('/api/v1/tasks') )
console.log('33333 ' + tasks)
```

[image]

[image]

Issue is: `tasks is undefined`

Comment: Why do you think the problem is in the frontend?

Comment: Have you tried getting the response as it is and checking it? Without deconstructing

Comment: Can you post the express function which handles the GET `/api/v1/tasks` route?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was in Backend..
the route associated with await axios.get('/api/v1/tasks') i.e get('/api/v1/tasks') had this code

````
``` const getAllTasks = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const tasks = await Task.find({})
        res.status(200).json(tasks)
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500).send({msg: error})
    }
}```
instead above. It should be
```const getAllTasks = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const tasks = await Task.find({})
        res.status(200).json({ tasks })
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500).send({msg: error})
    }
}```
````

The change is in res.status(200).json({ tasks })